# No method error after adding a some HTML with embedded ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The code below works as it should, but after adding a dropdown navigation with some embedded ruby, I get a no method error.

> NoMethodError in Static_pages#home
> Showing D:/Ruby/sample_app/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb where line #9 raised:
> undefined method `find_by_token' for #Class:0x467a948

My _header.html.erb which gives no errors

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
     <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "Energy Battle", root_path, id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home",    root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help",    help_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Log in", signin_path %></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
     </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

This is the _header.html.erb with the code I added. Which gives me the error.

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "Energy Battle", root_path, id: "logo" %>
       <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
          <% if signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
         <% end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's telling you that there is a problem with your `signed_in?` method.

That's where you need to start checking.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have a signed_in? method in my sessions_helper.rb

def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

Comment: So following the next step, the problem is in current_user.  Basically it's a case of following the rabbit down the hole!  Look for the find_by_token call and see how that's working

Comment: Thank you, I managed to solve my problem. It turned out I made a mistake in the my sessions_helper.rb.